# Homomorphism from noncompact semisimple Lie group to compact Lie group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is it true that there is no homomorphism from a semisimple Lie group without compact factor to a compact Lie group?

Comment: Wouldn't such a map *be* a compact factor of the original Lie group?

Comment: @LSpice I don't see why the image would be normal. However, the non-existence of a nontrivial/injective homomorphism (there's always the trivial homomorphism) follows, for instance, from the fact that the affine group $\mathbf{R}\ltimes\mathbf{R}$ has no faithful finite-dimensional unitary representation.

Comment: This question is strictly covered in [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250487/faithful-finite-dimensional-unitary-representations/373591#373591) which was answered in comments. I have now provided the detailed answer there.

Comment: @YCor, maybe I don't know the terminology.  I thought a compact factor just meant a quotient with compact image.  I believe that there are obstructions (which is why I just asked in a comment); I just don't see why it [matters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373569/homomorphism-from-noncompact-semisimple-lie-group-to-compact-lie-group#comment945460_373569) whether the image of that quotient is normal in some larger compact group.  Is the issue whether the kernel is an almost direct factor?

Comment: But the problem is that it's not a priori obvious that the image is closed. So the quotient by the kernel might be noncompact.

Answer (score 4):

See below a detailed version of the comment of @LSpice. (Edited taking into account a comment of @YCor.) This is an answer to the question on homomorpisms of real *algebraic* groups.

> **Proposition.**
> Let $\varphi\colon G\to K$ be a homomorphism of real *algebraic* groups, where $G$ is a connected semisimple real algebraic group without compact factors and $K$ is a compact real algebraic group.
> Then $\varphi$ is trivial (identically 1).

*Proof.*  Such a homomorphism $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism
$$ G/{\rm ker}\,\varphi\,\overset\sim\longrightarrow\, {\rm im\,}\varphi.$$
The image   ${\rm im\,}\varphi$ is closed in $K$. Therefore, ${\rm im\,}\varphi$ is compact. On the other hand, from the theory of real semisimple algebraic groups we know that since $G$ is a connected semisimple real algebraic group without compact *factors*, it has no nontrivial compact *quotients*.  It follows that  $G/{\rm ker}\,\varphi=\{1\}$, and hence $\varphi$ is trivial.

Note that any *compact* real Lie group is algebraic. However,  a noncompact real semisimple Lie group might be *non-algebraic*. For example, any nontrivial cover of ${\rm SL}(2, {\Bbb R})$ is non-algebraic.

Comment: I don't think this is a proof. It's a trivial reduction to showing that there's no injective homomorphism from a [nontrivial!] semisimple group with no compact factor into a compact Lie group. The remainder of the proof (which I mentioned in a comment, or alternatively doing the case when $G$ is locally isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$) is fairly standard (and probably quite a duplicate here), but contains all the substance of the proof, which is not apparent here. Just to keep in mind, there's an injective hom from the noncompact Lie group $\mathbf{R}$ into some compact Lie group.

Comment: @YCor: I agree. I had in mind real semisimple *algebraic* groups.

Comment: ... with algebraic homomorphisms. (Which is automatic among Lie group homomorphisms between semisimple algebraic groups, which is not hard but strictly harder this whole argument).

Answer (score 2):

I think an elementary argument is that if such a homomorphism exists, one can pull back the Cartan-Killing form (or an extension of that, in case the compact group has positive dimensional center) to an  Ad-invariant definite inner product on  the Lie algebra of a quotient of the original group. This quotient is then compact.

Comment: Indeed. This argument works in the broader setting of [this older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250487/faithful-finite-dimensional-unitary-representations/373591#373591).